# how can I get only data for nested element in xml using simple xml android

Tags: android, xml, xml-deserialization, simple-framework

I am hoping someone could help, and would really appreciate.

I am trying to create elements from an xml using [simple xml](http://simple.sourceforge.net) for android and I am not interested in the root, but only some nested elements. I wonder if there is a way for simple xml to get those elements without me creating all the classes starting from root(Response class in this case). I am only interested in getting the Stations class from the xml below.

Thank you.

```
    <Response xmlns="http://www.sss.com/ws/">
    <GroupInfo>
    <Id>lirr</Id>
    <Name>Long Island Rail Road</Name>
    <VehicleTypes>R</VehicleTypes>
    <Category>NYC to LI Regional Rail</Category>
    <IconLarge>
    <Width>50</Width>
    <Height>50</Height>
    </IconLarge>
    <Icon>
    <Width>25</Width>
    <Height>25</Height>
    </Icon>
    <Stations>
    <Station>
    <Id>albertson</Id>
    <Name>Albertson</Name>
    <X>-73.64169</X>
    <Y>40.77205</Y>
    <Radius>100</Radius>
    </Station>
    <Station>
    <Id>yaphank</Id>
    <Name>Yaphank</Name>
    <X>-72.91588</X>
    <Y>40.8256</Y>
    <Radius>100</Radius>
    </Station>
    </Stations>
    </GroupInfo>
    <ResponseStatus>
    <ResultCode>200</ResultCode>
    <ResultString>Success.</ResultString>
    </ResponseStatus>
    </Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I used @Path to specify the xpath and it solves the problem
http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#xpath